# hybridauth facebook display=popup setting not working

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, hybridauth

I'm using hybridauth-2.2.2 to implement facebook connect.
Connecting and login with facebook is not a problem.
At the moment my login page goes to the facebook login page and redirects back, but I want to open the facebook login dialog in a popup window, so I changed the setting display=page to display=popup but it still redirects to the facebook login page. I assume that I'm missing something so just wanted to know what. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you require more details.

Thanks,
Devo

Answer (score 0):

guess I was expecting too much of the hybridauth library this time. I thought the display=popup setting would add the js to open the pop up window itself, but I guess it's just to tell facebook api whats been used to connect. So just added the bit of js needed to open a popup window for facebook login

Comment: would be helpful for the community to know what you did to achieve the popup (or modal, lightbox etc) result you were looking for. Thanks!